# How to add saved images to mediastore and generate thumbnails?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android app which can take pictures and save them on the SD card. Later, I need to display the pictures in a GridView and the user can select one. This is my code to save pictures:

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {         
            currentPictureName = (String) getResources().getText(R.string.username) 
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(sdcardPath + currentPictureName);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }
```

However, none of the saved images have thumbnails to show in the GridView. How do I automatically generate thumbnails for all images that I save and add everything to `MediaStore` so that they can be accessed later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg63884.html). This works perfectly fine, all thumbnails are automatically generated

Answer (score 1):

Try using [scanFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function.

You must implement a media scanner connection client

```
private class ImageScannerClient implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

        @Override
        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
            // Start scanning files you have in a que
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            // Run some code, then maybe initiate scan of next file in que
        }

}
```

In onCreate you can connect to the media scanner like so:

```
    // Connect to media scanner
    this.mediaScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), new ImageScannerClient() );
    this.mediaScanner.connect();
```

And at some other point you must add files to a que or something to be scanned.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg63884.html
Trying this too

Comment: Will `scanFile()` automatically generate thumbnails too?